# firefox certificate validation ssl

Tags: firefox, ssl, certificate, validation

i'm experimenting with old FFes prior v53. My favorite is 'Light', a lean FF49. Due to out-dated certs i get errors for most https-sites. Sure i can make exceptions for each, but that's unnerving and lasts only 3 months.

Is there a kill-switch in about:config to override the cert-validation = make FF treat every https site like unencrypted http = accept outdated or non-existing certs as valid by default? If not, how can i import a to-date cert8.db? Copy & paste from more recent FFs does'nt work, maybe there are other files to consider?

Pls, i do'nt want to start a security-discussion. I'm aware of the risks when surfing to unverified sites, even exotic ones like https://google.com or wikipedia.org...

Answer (score 0):

You can override the settings with the Firefox-addon "Skip-Cert-Error". You'll find it in the old-FF-addon-catalog:

https://github.com/JustOff/ca-archive/releases

Comment: You describe an add-on called "Skip-Cert-Error", but your link is to "JustOff".